# Facebook Real Time update not working as expected

Tags: php, facebook, api, real-time

I registered for real time updates feature and I verified it as well here's the response which I get when I tried to see whether my subscription was success or not

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "object": "user",
         "callback_url": "http://ghl.raiseit-bd.com/callback-page.php",
         "fields": [
            "feed"
         ],
         "active": true
      }
   ]
}
```

Now when I made a post on my wall, I was expecting that facebook will call my callback url and things will get written to a text file

Here's code for callback-page.php

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == 'Our1stFBApp') {

   echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
   exit;

}
else
{
  $updates = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
  $myFile = "testFile.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  $stringData = $updates;
  $stringData = $stringData.'Hello';
  fwrite($fh, $stringData);
  fclose($fh);
  print_r($stringData, true));       

}

?>
```

the file textFile.txt resides inside root directory.

But nothings getting written in that file.
How will I know that the real-time update feature is working..any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do your server logs show any hits to that callback URL?

Comment: I just have ftp access to the server so dont how to check what you have mentioned.

Comment: It's not going to be fun troubleshooting if that's the case.

Comment: I just checked the subscribtion was successful as the $_GET['hub_challenge'] was written in text file, its just that when I am posting something on my wall, the real time update is not calling my call back url..as the text file is not getting updated at all in this case

Comment: Sounds like your app might not have the "read_stream" permission for the user whose wall you're posting on?

Comment: well I have read_stream permission and in this case I am posting on my wall only

Comment: Any update? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: How did you make subscription? can you please share the code?